# Perform subquery on another subquery's result in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery

Suppose there is table `Product` with columns `prod_id, a, b`

Suppose there is table `Warehouse` with columns `w_id, pid, amount`

The point is to join these two tables so that we would get in result columns `prod_id, a, b, total` (which is sum of the `amount` for `pid = prod_id`)

Currently I have this query:

```
SELECT
    t1.prod_id, a, b, c AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT prod_id, a, b
    FROM product
    WHERE ean = "3165142644363"
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT warehouse.pid, SUM(amount) AS c
    FROM warehouse
    WHERE warehouse.pid IN (SELECT prod_id FROM product WHERE ean = "3165142644363")
    GROUP BY warehouse.pid
) t2
    ON t2.pid = t1.prod_id
```

Now you see there is two similar but not identical queries:

```
SELECT prod_id, a, b FROM product WHERE ean = "3165142644363"

SELECT prod_id FROM product WHERE ean = "3165142644363"
```

Executing both of these queries takes too much time. Is there a way to execute only the first one and then select product id from the result of that subquery? Or any other efficient way to rewrite the query. Creating the view is not an option as there can be many queries all with different `ean` parameter. The query returns more than one row of data for the same `ean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found a solution myself. Way easier than I thought:

```
SELECT pid, a, b, SUM(amount) AS total
FROM product
LEFT JOIN warehouse USING(pid)
WHERE ean = "3165142644363"
GROUP BY pid
```

In my example there are columns `prod_id` and `pid`, but in fact it is `pid` in both tables

Comment: This query is only valid if `pid` is a primary key on the `product` table.  If not, then your query would either not run, or it would give non deterministic results.  In any case, +1 for seeing a simple solution.

Comment: `pid` is primary query in `product` table. Sorry I didn't mention it

Answer (score 1):

I think you can remove the subquery appearing after `WHERE ... IN`:

```
SELECT
    t1.prod_id, a, b, c AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT prod_id, a, b
    FROM product
    WHERE ean = '3165142644363'
) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT warehouse.pid, SUM(amount) AS c
    FROM warehouse
    GROUP BY warehouse.pid
) t2
    ON t2.pid = t1.prod_id
```

The reason you can remove it is that the `t2` subquery would only contain `pid` values which appear in the `t1` subquery.  Otherwise, the sum `c` would just be zero anyway after the left join.  A left join already implicitly handles the case where records from `product` may not join to anything in the `t2` subquery.

That being said, removing the `WHERE ... IN` subquery might not improve performance that much, because it is not correlated anyway.  Most likely the optimizer would only need to compute it once and cache it somewhere.

Comment: Your query took around 20 seconds to execute in my table. Eventually I found the answer without using join

Comment: For clarification: my original query on the same table took around 11 seconds so the efficiency has not improved

Comment: @Alvis Do you have an index on the `ean` column in the `product` table?

Comment: Yes there is index. Anyway, I found a way to simplify the query and now it takes like 0,016 sec to execute, check my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another formulation that might be better:

```
SELECT  pid, a, b, 
        ( SELECT  SUM(amount)
            FROM  wherehouse
            WHERE  pid = product.prod_id 
        ) AS total
    FROM  product
    WHERE  ean = "3165142644363";
```

With indexes:

```
product: INDEX(ean)
wherehouse: INDEX(pid, amount)  -- in this order
```